# I want to extract a certain paragraph from a text type website using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.6, text-extraction

website = https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt

I want to extract paragraph named by "MANAGEMENT'S DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS OF FINANCIAL CONDITION AND RESULTS OF OPERATIONS" in  text format in python from the given link using for loop.

Comment: What code have you written to do this and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: See also [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) (tl;dr: never)

Comment: The problem of extracting specific Items from EDGAR filings has been discussed very frequently. Search for the Q&As - but you should know: it's very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python urllib2 library to do this.

Example of python code:

```
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen("https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt")  # read file
data = data.split("\n") # then split it into lines

for line in data:
    if line = "MANAGEMENT'S DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS OF FINANCIAL CONDITION AND RESULTS OF OPERATIONS"
    print line # or what you want to do
```

Comment: I want the whole paragraph i.e. from page 14 to page 19 in this link. But in a generalised format

Comment: How is page delimetered in your .txt file? There must be delimeter